# Does inner product equality imply equality?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is regarding a proof method that seems suspect to me. In Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* (3rd edn 2014), chapter 7, p. 205, he proves that the adjoint is a linear map. I'll reproduce the structure of the proof minus some details here for reference:

> Suppose $T\in L(V, W)$. Fix $w_1,w_2 \in W$. If $v \in V$, then
> $$\langle v, T^*(w_1 + w_2)\rangle = [\ldots] = \langle v, T^*w_1 + T^*w_2 \rangle,$$
> which shows that $T^*(w_1 + w_2) = T^*w_1 + T^*w_2$.

What seems suspect here is the last line; namely, he seems to be relying on some hidden principle that for any $S,T \in L(V, W)$,
$$\langle v, Sw\rangle = \langle v, Tw\rangle\implies S=T,$$
but this is simply untrue. As a counterexample, take $V=W=\mathbb{R}$ and $v=(0, 1), w=(1, 0),$ and $S:a\mapsto 2a$, $T: a \mapsto 3a$,  $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\langle v, Sw\rangle = \langle(0, 1), (2, 0)\rangle = 0$ and $\langle v, Tw\rangle = \langle(0, 1), (3, 0)\rangle = 0$, so $\langle v, Sw\rangle = \langle v, Tw\rangle$ but $S \neq T$.

Am I missing something else that could make his proof valid?

Comment: It is a matter of quantifiers.  Axler says if, for all $u,v$ the equation holds, then the nice consequence follows.  Your give an example where the equation holds for one particular pair $u,v$, but not for all pairs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The essence is that
\begin{equation}
{\color{violet}{\forall v}}\ \forall w\ \ \langle v, Sw\rangle = \langle v, Tw\rangle\implies S=T.
\end{equation}
The proof for the fact:
For any $w$, take $v=Sw-Tw$. Then
\begin{align}
&\langle v, Sw\rangle = \langle v, Tw\rangle,\ \text{i.e.} \langle Sw-Tw, Sw\rangle = \langle Sw-Tw, Tw\rangle\\
\implies & 0=\langle Sw-Tw, Sw\rangle -\langle Sw-Tw, Tw\rangle =\langle Sw-Tw,,Sw-Tw\rangle\\
\overset{\text{positivity}}{\implies}& Sw-Tw=0,\ \text{i.e.} Sw=Tw.
\end{align}

In your example, $\langle v, Sw\rangle = \langle v, Tw\rangle$ does not hold for all $v$. For instance it does not hold for $v=(1,0)$.

Comment: I believe you mean for all v and w in the first line ?

Comment: Without wanting to nitpick too much, the quantifier should also be at the front to be grammatical. The current ordering matches how you would read it in English, but is harder to read as a formula.

Comment: @aboves Yes, your suggestions are very true. I have edited my answer. Thanks a lot for pointing out the flaws.

Answer (score 5):

If $\langle v,a\rangle=\langle v,b\rangle$ for **all** $v\in V$ then $a=b$.

Answer (score 3):

In Axler's phrase *"If $v \in V$, then..."* there is a hidden universal quantifier. This is a quite common style in mathematical writing, which one must get used to.

To unveil that quantifier using more words one can write something like this: *"For all $v \in V$, the following holds..."*

Comment: Axler seems to be expecting "fix" to be taken as a universal quantifier.

Comment: That too, although it seems like the quantifier that is relevant to the OP's question seems to be the *"If $v \in V$"* quantifier.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is a better answer. This relies on the following fact.

**Lemma.** If $\langle v,w_1\rangle=\langle v,w_2\rangle$ for all $v \in V$, then $w_1=w_2$.

The proof is as follows. $\langle v,w_1\rangle=\langle v,w_2\rangle$ for all $v \in V$ implies that $\langle v,w_1-w_2\rangle=0$ for all $v \in V$, which in turn implies that $w_1-w_2=0$ and therefore $w_1=w_2$ (otherwise we would have $|w_1-w_2|^2=\langle w_1-w_2, 
w_1-w_2\rangle > 0$).

A direct application of the lemma proves that
\begin{equation}
\langle v, Sw\rangle = \langle v, Tw\rangle\ \ {\color{violet}{\forall v}}\implies S w=Tw.
\end{equation}

If you want equality of the operators, you need $Sw=Tw$ for all $w\in V$, so the lemma implies that

\begin{equation}
\langle v, Sw\rangle = \langle v, Tw\rangle\ \ {\color{violet}{\forall v,w}}\implies S=T.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Axler have shown that
$$\tag{1}\label{1} \langle v,T^*(w_1+w_2) \rangle=\langle v,T^*(w_1)+T^*(w_2) \rangle$$
for all $v\in V$. Note that we can rewrite $(\ref{1})$ as
$$0=\langle v,T^*(w_1)+T^*(w_2)\rangle-\langle v,T^*(w_1+w_2) \rangle\\
\implies0=\langle v,T^*(w_1)+T^*(w_2)-T^*(w_1+w_2) \rangle$$
Since this is true for all $v\in V$, we can choose $v_0=T^*(w_1)+T^*(w_2)-T^*(w_1+w_2)$ to obtain
$$\tag{2}\label{2}0=\langle T^*(w_1)+T^*(w_2)-T^*(w_1+w_2),T^*(w_1)+T^*(w_2)-T^*(w_1+w_2) \rangle.$$
From the definition of inner product, we know that $\langle u,u\rangle=0$ if and only if $u=0$. Therefore, we conclude from $(\ref{2})$ that
$$T^*(w_1)+T^*(w_2)=T^*(w_1+w_2).$$